# MMSE estimator using pmf table

Tags: probability, estimation, parameter-estimation

We have the probability mass function as follows, $$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{Y=0} & \text{Y=1} \\ \hline
\text{X=0} & \frac 15 & \frac 25 \\ \hline
\text{X=1} & \frac 25 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$ I want to calculate the $\hat x_M$ MMSE estimator of $X$ given $Y$, and its MSE (Minimum-squared-error).
I know $\hat x_M=E[X|Y=y]$. I tried by calculating $E[X|Y=y]$, which is equal to $\sum x{\rho_{X|Y}(x|y)}=\sum x\frac{\rho_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\rho_{Y}(y)}$, and obtained $E[X|Y=0]=\frac{2}{3}$ and $E[X|Y=1]=0$. But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Do you know how to compute $\mathbb{E}(X|Y=y)$ for $y=0,1$?

Comment: Yes, $E[X|Y=y]=\sum x{\rho_{X|Y}(x|y)}=\sum x\frac{\rho_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\rho_{Y}(y)}$ and is equal to 2/3 for y=0 and 0 for y=1.

Comment: You should include your attempts in your original post or else your question will most likely receive downvotes and be closed. Showing your efforts will also encourage other site users to guide you to the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks dear Matthew, I edited my question.

Comment: Great. So you can say $\hat{X}_M=\frac{2}{3}(1-Y)$. Now, do you know how to evaluate $\mathbb{E}\left((X-\hat{X}_M)^2\big|Y=y\right)$ for $y=0,1$?

Comment: $E[(X-\hat X_M)^2|Y=0]=E[(X+\frac23Y-\frac23)^2|Y=0]=E[(X-\frac23)^2]=E[X^2]-\frac43E[X]+\frac49=\frac{14}{45}$ and $E[(X-\hat X_M)^2|Y=1]=E[X^2]=\frac25.$